# Details related to the ZIP algorithm used in PGP message encryption?

Tags: protocol-design, authenticated-encryption, pgp

I am very new to PGP. PGP encryption works with hash function, asymmetric encryption, symmetric encryption and a zip algorithm (LZ77). What I know is that the zip algorithm is used to reduce the length of message which has repeating characters, but the algorithm consist of two encoding schemes which are:

```
-- <0> < 8-bit pointer length> <4-bit length>
-- <1> <12-bit pointer length> <6-bit length>
```

Can you tell me the difference between them? Because version 1 may be can only take 14 bit input at once for conducting the comparison, but the version 2 can take 20 bit input at once for comparison…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a compression algorithm. It's not a cryptographic question even if that compression is used by crypto tools.

Comment: Okok,I get it now,so can I ask my question at stack information security ?

Comment: No, this question is off-topic on a site about cryptography or security, since it has nothing to do with either. It would be on-topic on [su] since it's about how an end user tool works. But your question is not clear. Have you looked up the specification of this algorithm? What do you mean by “the difference between them”? They're different algorithms, obviously. Do you understand how they work? If not, start with that, before comparing them.

Comment: Since the question is (AFAICT) about the zip compression algorithm, it might be on topic here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/